# What is this construction? (Sentence Structure) - 4

Tags: grammar, nouns, syntactic-analysis, sentence, construction

**The most handsome boy in the class, Sam**.

I remember seeing a sentence of this type in a book. I don't remember which. Can such a sentence be called a Sentence?

It contains only a **Noun** and an **Appositive phrase**.

Comment: It's not a sentence. Where's the verb?

Comment: I do think it is not a sentence, since there is no verb. But then again I've seen such a construction in a novel.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a complete sentence to function in a novel.

Comment: Okay. I think my doubt is cleared. 

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/258/shortest-comprehensive-sentence-in-english, https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/96484/does-standard-english-include-non-trivial-sentences-which-admit-no-verb, and https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54369/is-a-sentence-always-grammatically-incorrect-if-it-has-no-verb. Cheers!

Comment: There's no consensus. 

Comment: It's not a sentence, but a noun phrase.